# Need some help!

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Sorry, this question might sound silly, but I need some help!

My project is to open a directory and list all the files. These are csv files. Each file is opened and the contents are loaded into the table in a mysql database.

So I have done the above steps, and my java code works fine. For instance, I have 3 files in the directory. When I run the project, the values in each of the 3 files are loaded into the mysql table.

But when I run the program again and check the database using `Select` statement, it shows me the repeated data and hence the values of 6 files are loaded. When I run it again, the database shows 9 files. But I dont want the files to be added again.

So can anyone please tell me about how to achieve this without the need to delete the already added files from the directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have included primary key. This didnt happen before. I recently made some enhancements: retrieved the column values from the database and displayed it in a html file. From then on, my code behaves with this problem. So, i reset the project code to the old state. But also the problem still resides.

Comment: "Sorry, this question might sound silly, .."  Even sillier is that you *forgot to ask a question.*  (A statement of need is not a question.)

Comment: Alright! I am really sorry!! Will not repeat this mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a Unique file identifier in DB and in physical file also.

Check for this if it exist skip else perform DB operation

Comment: Thanks. Can you please help with a sample code?

Comment: For what specifically ? DB related or File IO related ?

Comment: How to check whether the filename already exists in the table before doing the insert operation?. I have the filename values as 2nd column. Would something like INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME("no", "name", "add")WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE name = " "); should help achieve this?

Comment: use Simple [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/), and fire some thinglike  `Select COUNT(FILE_ID) from FILE_MASTER where FILE_NAME='abc.txt';`

Comment: You are always welcome (also to accept answer :) )

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach: add another table to the database to record the names of those files that have already been processed.

Then, before writing the contents of a new file to the database: check this table first, if the file name is already on the list.

---

Alternative: record the timestamp of the last "run" and for all runs, skip those files that are "older".

But anyhow, you have to persist some sort of marker, because you need to remember, what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to the table which is the file name of the file you are reading. So in total you would have 2 columns, 1 for the file name, 1 for the file data.

Before inserting, check, using the SELECT statement if that filename has already been read and inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You could store additional information into the database what files did you already import.
You can store in an additional table the name and the *last-modified*-property of the imported file and make a reference t it in the *contents*-table.
Based on this information you can decide where to import a new file from the directory or just to update the contents of an already imported file.